# VideoJS Implementation with Fairplay DRM(reactJS)

Tags: reactjs, video.js, drm

I am trying to implement videoJS with Apple DRM(reactJS).
But getting this error

> {"errorcode":371000005,"errormsg":"Fairplay license acquisition failed >> Invalid FairPlay parameters format, 'spc=' or 'assetid=' prefix expected","errorid":"5048a2ad-57fc-4449-8f2e-4e95b16a9083"}

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you cannot use the keysystems certificateUri and licenseUri values for Fairplay License acquisition, at least not with Microsoft Azure Media Services.

I had to implement this with function based license validation, and passing the 'spc=' prefix to the message body in the getLicense() function.